# Need suggestion on a namedtuple example

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a program which takes Roll Number, Name & Marks of Physics, Chemistry and Mathematics of 3 Students. Calculate total marks & percentage for all students & display the merit list on screen.

I tried this with 'namedtuple' but I have got stuck, I dunno if my approach is wrong.

```
from collections import namedtuple

SInfo = namedtuple('SInfo', 'RNo Name M_P M_C M_M')

student1 = SInfo('123','Appy','60','90','65')
student2 = SInfo('124','Banny','30','60','75')
student3 = SInfo('125','Sammy','50','70','85')

students = [student1,student2,student3]

result = {}

for i in range(0,3):
    Total_Marks = int(students[i].M_P) + int(students[i].M_C) + int(students[i].M_M)
    list1 = []
    list1.append(students[i].Name) # Student Name
    list1.append(Total_Marks) # Total Marks
    list1.append(Total_Marks/3) # Percentage
    result[students[i].RNo] = list1
```

Now if I print the 'res' dictionary, I get the following (as expected):

```
print result
{'123': ['Appy', 215, 71], '124': ['Banny', 165, 55], '125': ['Sammy', 205, 68]}
```

Now I want to sort the total marks and display the corresponding names and percentage accordingly.

I am not sure how to sort the Total marks and stay connected with the student name.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted). It can take a `key` argument, which should be a function that returns the value to sort the sequence with.

```
>>> res = {'123': ['Appy', 215, 71], '124': ['Banny', 165, 55], '125': ['Sammy', 205, 68]}
>>> sorted(res.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][2], reverse=True)
[('123', ['Appy', 215, 71]), 
 ('125', ['Sammy', 205, 68]), 
 ('124', ['Banny', 165, 55])]
```

`lambda item: item[1][2]` means a function that maps something like this:

```
(RNo, (Name, Total, Percentage)) -> Total
```

If I can make a suggestion for your code, lists are usually not used for things that are not of the same type. You should use a tuple, or even better, a namedtuple (maybe one called `STotal`?)

```
result[students[i].RNo] = (students[i].Name, 
                           Total_Marks, 
                           Total_Marks/3)
```

Comment: hey thanks!!...just one question, what does 'reverse=True' here mean?

Comment: @user3342969 It means sort in descending order i.e. higher numbers first. Since you're calculating scores, I assumed you want the first one to have the highest score.